# Updating innerHTML with HTML from a php function? (using xajax)

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, xajax

I'm successfully updating the innerHTML of a DIV through xajax (when I click a link) but only when I assign HTML in the function itself, not when I call it from a different function.

To explain

```
  // For the sake of testing
$output=rand(20,40);

  // Add new HTML to container through $output
$ajax_resp->assign('div_container','innerHTML', $output);

return $ajax_resp;
```

This works fine. When I call this function through clicking the link, the container updates with a random number. However when I change $output to

```
$output=$compile->show('text');
```

Which is (simplified)

`function show($var)    { echo $var; }`

It does not show it. The function `show` works perfectly outside of xajax. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function show($var) { echo $var; }
```

This function doesn't return anything, it echo's the value to the screen. However, most functions you probably want to return a value, so they can work with it. Basically, when you  do

```
$output=$compile->show('text');
```

It will get no input from the show method, because show doesn't return any value. I think if you change it to the following:

```
function show($var) { return $var; }
```

It will work.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The issue with that is I'm using the `show` function throughout my website as a generic output handler. If I were to change it to `return` not `echo` it would mean updating hundreds of instances of it being called.

Comment: Okay, but if you can't change the show method, because it will break other functionality, you'll have to find another way. Because the only way to let `$ajax-resp->assign()` know what to handle with, is to return a value to it. But since you want to do something else that you do with `Show()` normally, perhaps it's a good idea to create a new function for what you wan to do now.

Comment: Additionally, every time you call `show` you will `echo` something on the page, so if you use `show` to return a message, it will also show somewhere on the page.

Comment: To solve your problem with the show() function, just add a second parameter ( `show($text, $return_type = null)` ) and change your function to return the value instead of echoing it when you set this second parameter to `true`. This way you dont have to change every call to this function

Comment: I'm creating a whole new section for my website, so maybe a new function would be a good idea. The `show` function is actually a very simple table-like design that I can easily duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change `function show($var) { echo $var; }` to `function show($var) { return $var; }`. Should solve your problem

Comment: Timo Willemsen just suggested that, and I will try it.